# Rotation down a plane problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, rotational-kinematics, moment-of-inertia, angular-velocity

I need help with calculations, here is what I have:

I rolled a ring down an inclined plane. 
I have the time it takes to roll one revolution (2pi). 
It started at rest. 
I have the mass of the ring.
I can calculate the ring's moment of inertia with (1/2)mr^2.

How do I obtain angular momentum, angular acceleration, and torque?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

First, the moment of inertia of a ring is $I=mR^2$, not $\frac{1}{2}mR^2$.

Second, under the assumption that the ring does not slip as it rolls, then you can find the angular velocity $\omega = \frac{v}{R}$, where $v$ is the translational velocity of the center of mass.  Once you know that, you can find the other quantities immediately as per their definitions:
$$ L = I\omega$$
$$ \alpha = \frac{d\omega}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{v}{R}\right) = \frac{a}{R}$$
$$ \tau = I\alpha $$